# Thread finishing execution before printing

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer

I am writing to a file (Java) while I execute some code. Below you can find the code used, which is executed by the "Thread B", invoked by the JVM.

```
writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("table.csv")));

(...)


while ( (m_bEnExecution) && (!m_bFinTestRules) ) {

   //Calculate new rule
   CalculateNewRule(writer);
}

writer.close();
```

Inside the CalculateNewRule method, a new instantiation of an AssociationRule is created, which will receive the writer as an instance variable. One of the functions inside AssociationRule does the printing.

```
writer.println(outputRule);
writer.flush();
```

The problem seems to be that this function is invoked by an AWT thread, and the last line to be written to the file, inside the CalculateNewRule(writer) method will never be written, unless I explicitly force the execution of the thread to stop, after the while cycle. Any idea on what the problem might be? Is there any elegant way to deal with this problem?

In one answer I was suggested to set the printing thread as a daemon thread, but I don't know how to do that on that specific thread.

Comment: Please provide piece of code responsible for writing to the file. Where it is located? What is inside `CalculateNewRule`. Right now it is hard to help you - not enough info.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the calling thread is getting over before this thread finishes. Use a daemon thread if this is the case.
Provide more details maybe we can help.

Comment: The thread which is responsible to print to the file is an AWT thread. I'm still trying to figure out on how to make that thread daemon, but I think this will fix the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Is that "(m_bEnExecution) && (!m_bFinTestRules)" always equals true??

I suggest that as below:

```
try {
  while ( (m_bEnExecution) && (!m_bFinTestRules) ) {

    //Calculate new rule
    CalculateNewRule(writer);
    writer.flush();
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  writer.close();
}
```

But you still need to make sure that you will not make the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! it's not an infinite loop. I tried with the finally clause and it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing much code but anyway.

What do you mean:

> force the execution of the thread to stop

You are using a `BufferedWriter` so unless you `flush`, `close` etc the writer you are not sure it has written everything in the buffer.

If you want to be sure just choose one of these methods.

Comment: You are right, I didn't provide that much code :/ 

Inside the CalculateNewRule method I print the lines, as well as I flush the buffer afterwards.

Comment: Edited the first comment with more information concerning the problem